# Lambda Expression StartDate of the Month and End Date of Month

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, lambda

```
 startDate = DateTime.Now;
            endDate = DateTime.Now;
            ResponseDeliveryOrderCountDetails monthDeliveryOrderEarning = (from deliveryBoys in db.tblDeliveryBoys
                                                                           where deliveryBoys.Mobile == mobile
                                                                           select new ResponseDeliveryOrderCountDetails()
                                                                           {
                                                                               // OrdersCount = (from earnings in db.tblDeliveryEarnings.Where(x => x.DeId == deliveryBoys.DeId && x.DeliveryStatus == 1 && x.DeliveryStatus == 1 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveryDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveryDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate)).GroupBy(y => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(y.DeliveryDate))
                                                                               //select earnings.ToList().Count).ToList(),
                                                                               OrderCount = (from earnings in db.tblDeliveryEarnings.Where(x => x.DeId == deliveryBoys.DeId && x.DeliveryStatus == 1 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveryDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveryDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate)).GroupBy(y => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(y.DeliveryDate))
                                                                                             select earnings.ToList().Count).ToList().Sum(),
                                                                               Earnings = db.tblDeliveryEarnings.Where(x => x.DeId == deliveryBoys.DeId && x.DeliveryStatus == 1 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveryDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveryDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate)).ToList().Select(x => x.Earnings.Value).Sum(),
                                                                               WorkingHours = db.tblDeliveryAttenances.Where(x => x.DeId == deliveryBoys.DeId && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.SlotDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(startDate) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.SlotDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate)).ToList().Select(x => x.WorkingHours.Value).Sum(),
                                                                               DeliverEarnEnum = DeliveryEarningEnum.CurrentMonth.ToString()

                                                                           }).FirstOrDefault();



            responseDeliveryOrderCountDetails.Add(monthDeliveryOrderEarning);
```

I have a Lambda Expression where I need to evaluate the data from Start Date of Current Month and End Date of Current Month.

Is there any way I can set the start date and End date?

Comment: There is no need for `TruncateTime`. Get midnight of the first of this month (`startDate`). Add a month to it (`endDateExclusive`). Check the dates are >= startDate and < endDateExclusive . _This is assuming you are interested in all data for this current month._

Comment: DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);